# Data generated from smart bulbs?

Tags: smart-home, lighting, analytics

I'm trying to answer 2 questions mainly:

1. What kinds of data are generated from 1 branch of IoT devices namely smart bulbs/smart lighting?
2. How can we visualize the data generated by the same?

I searched online specifically on the same but could not find a lot of useful information. If any of you could help answer this question with relevant resource URLs, it would greatly help me for a school presentation on the same.

Comment: [*Is there a fully open source platform for IoT presentation and visualization?*](http://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/168/is-there-a-fully-open-source-platform-for-iot-presentation-and-visualization) might be of interest for the visualisation aspect.

Comment: You tagged this with *Philips Hue*, is your question singular to those bulbs or referring to the complete class of smart bulbs?

Comment: My question is referring to the complete class of smart bulbs Helmar :)

Comment: Is there a spec? I get a feeling each manufacturer is working on proprietary designs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The bulbs themselves do not generate data. You might see data being generated by a building management system, where sensors are used to determine where and how to light the rooms.

It's conceivable that a smart-home lighting system can generate analytics based on user requests for lighting, but there is nothing obviously interesting about this data (even when it's aggregated). Lighting is a little different to something like domestic heating where the demand varies daily, and can usefully be automatically moderated.

When you think about visualising data, you need to identify one or two variables (maybe several times) which represent ways to break down the data. For lighting, you could look at phases of a day (morning, day, evening, night) and see how they vary from day of the week - but I think you'll find the data very sparse.

Answer (score 1):

The bulbs, in fact, do generate data. They report their state to central hubs or perhaps, faraway servers, and this data can be queried, or even acted on, like a bulb that autumatically turns off during the day.