# Which IoT platform to visualize real-time and historical sensor data?

Tags: mqtt, raspberry-pi, esp8266, esp32, https

In order to prepare some tutorials for my students, I am working on a few DIY electronics projects in the field of IoT. I want to use **ESP32**, **ESP8266**, **Arduino Uno**, and **Raspberry Pi**. I am more deep on firmware/hardware part and I have no experience on cloud application.

I know that there are some IoT PaaS such as **Azure IoT**, **AWS**, **Google**, etc. As I want to develop some simple prototypes, I just want to send the data to the cloud and visualize them without any back-end coding skills and all the mentioned services requires additional expertise to show the data (DB, UI/UX,...).

I googled to find simplified solution and these services popped up:

- [uBeac](https://www.ubeac.io/?utm_source=iot.stackexchange.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=4039)
- [TagoIO](https://tago.io/)
- [ThingsBoard](https://thingsboard.io/)
- [freeboard](https://freeboard.io/)
- [myDevices](https://mydevices.com/)
- [Losant](https://www.losant.com/)
- [thethings](https://thethings.io/)
- [Thinger](https://thinger.io/)

I need to send data via **HTTP** and **MQTT** to the cloud service and visualize the sent data.

My question is which service is more suitable for my use case? Is there any other service that I missed? And the more important one: what are the key factors to evaluate such services?

Comment: Be sure to post your answers below, everyone — the comments here are meant for clarifying the question rather than offering partial solutions. Have you also seen [*Is there a fully open source platform for IoT presentation and visualization?*](https://iot.stackexchange.com/q/168/12) for some ideas?

Comment: [guide to iot platforms and dashboards](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/iot-mqtt-dashboards/)

Comment: I am also a beginner with regards to IoT-cloud services and dashboards, and I'm looking for a suitable service. I couldn't help but notice that your hardware platform is included in a bunch of examples on ThingsBoard, for instance https://thingsboard.io/docs/samples/esp8266/temperature/. An overview of all examples: https://thingsboard.io/docs/guides/#AnchorIDHardwareSamples. Whether ThingsBoard is the best choice for you project is another matter...

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend [NodeRed](https://nodered.org/) .Simple drag and drop visual programming by IBM based on Nodejs .NodeRed can be installed easily using npm (package manager in Nodejs sililar to pip for python).Please read offficial documentation for installation and usage.You can install mqtt broker like mosquitto and add mqtt capability to NodeRED.

Thinger.io is also quiet simple.Its an opensource platform that supports mqtt protocol.simple interface to add device, generate security token as well as simple to add graph

Comment: How about a bit more information about the two?

Comment: Intro to NodeRED: https://developer.ibm.com/open/projects/node-red/

Answer (score 2):

Another option is ThingSpeak: https://thingspeak.com/

This platform allows you to send data using http request and visualise in graphic yous sensors. Besides, you can create 'alerts' to send a message when some sensor reach an exact value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ubidots](https://ubidots.com/education/) platform for data visualization.

It provides very good graphical representation of your data.

Comment: Can you get a bit more specific?

Answer (score 1):

there are several IoT platform that can visualize data in real time and historical information. Almost all support MQTT and HTTP so they match your needs. 
They are platforms that are not free while others provide a free account you can use to experiment with your project.
Just to name a few:

Ubidots

Temboo

TheThings.io

Xively

myDevices Cayenne

Kaa

If you want to have more information you can give a look at my post at https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2018/10/iot-platforms-overview-to-build-iot-projects.html

Let me know if you need more information.